# Форматирование флешки. OC Linux vs WINDOWS

Tags: linux, windows, форматирование

Запустил я быстрое форматирование на ***OC WINDOWS*** и оно оказалось медленным по сравнению с утилитой **GPARTED** в ***OC LINUX*** и вот, на фоне этого я захотел узнать в чем же разница между, казалось бы, простыми действиями как форматирование. Разницу между быстрым и полным форматированием в ***OC WINDOWS*** я нашел. Она в том, что, предварительно флешка забивается нулями. Вопрос в том ПОЧЕМУ ТАК ДОЛГО ПРОИСХОДИТ НА ***WINDOWS*** ФОРМАТИРОВАНИЕ. Спасибо! Форматирование под FAT32

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём... *Разницу между быстрым и полным форматированием в OC WINDOWS я нашел. Она в том, что, предварительно флешка забивается нулями.* Неверно - хотя и близко к истине.

Comment: злые языки поговаривают про банальный таймаут, вставленный ради того, чтобы придать больше солидности процессу форматирования.

Comment: Файловая система какая в обоих случаях?

Comment: Вы путаете **форматирование** и **создание логистического диска**. Сравнивайте апельсины с апельсинами.

Comment: В Линуксе все быстрее, хотя бы потому что дрова не [пишутся индусами](https://lurkmore.to/_/1806#mws_bkKugI8). Переходите на GNU Linux!

Comment: Повторяю вопрос: какая файловая система используется? | На линуксе вы действительно _форматируете_ или просто _разбиваете на разделы_?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, под fat32